# Calling an error-first function Node JS

Tags: node.js, function, error-handling, function-calls

new to Node and having fun, however, I am encountering an issue trying to pass data to a function that has two arguments err/argTime. ex:function(err, argTime).

This works for me:

```
queryTrigger(moment()); //the call
//more code...

function queryTrigger(argTime) { 
            console.log(argTime);
         };
```

This does not work:

```
queryTrigger(moment()); //the call
//more code...

function queryTrigger(err, argTime) { 
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
        console.log(argTime);
        };
};
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: In second case use `queryTrigger(null, moment());`, because the first parameter is error.

Comment: Thanks! That was quick and works. Short follow-up: is it good practice to add an error argument to a simple function like this?

Comment: Usually `error` parameter used in async function. In your function it's not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a value as the error, but in the case there isn't one you can use either `null` or `undefined` as the value (to represent no error).

```
// No error:
queryTrigger(null, moment());

// Explicit error:
queryTrigger((new Error('Error!')), moment());

// Variable error from function response:
queryTrigger(isErrored(), moment());
```

In answer to your follow-up comment, you typically only need this pattern when calling asynchronous functions where the error is raised outside of the main event loop - if you're not doing so, you can just use `try/catch` to deal with errors.

I disagree with the statement in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45745822/1690108) with regards to best practices; the `err` argument is basically always going to be the first argument and is followed by pretty much every async function in the stdlib along with most (good) packages on GitHub/npm.

Comment: I've added some code to your answer, as I think that is a good aspect of the other answer, even though I disagree with the best practices statement also. Seemed more logical than writing my own